# opencv waitKey(0) triggers without keypress

Tags: python, opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a short python script that shows an image with cv2.imshow() and then waits until a key is pressed with cv2.waitKey(0)

```py
import cv2 as cv

...

cv.imshow("Preview", img)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
print(k)
```

The first time I run the script, it works fine (waits until a key is pressed, and then closes the window and continues the script). However, the second time I run the script, it detects the key I previously used to close the window even though I'm not pressing it.

#### My setup:

Im using WSL2 kernel 5.10.16.3 with Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 Pro 21376.1 (insider preview for WSLg). using Windows Terminal as my terminal. I've also tested by running wsl through powershell and the issue is the same.

edit:
If i run `cv.waitKey(1)` in a loop and print the output, it looks equivalent to holding down the corresponding key:

```
> -1
> -1
> -1
> 106
> -1
> -1
> -1
> -1
> 106
> -1
> -1
> -1
> 106
```

and so on

edit2: pressing any key physically stops the phantom keypresses. I dont know if there is some way to programmatically press a key at the start of the script.. that might be a viable workaround.

Comment: Try flushing the stdout buffer after print. `import sys;
sys.stdout.flush()` Tell me if it worked and I will explain

Comment: didnt work unfortunately. tried flushing at start of script, before imshow, after imshow but before waitkey, and after waitkey and print.. none worked.

Comment: it rather looks like some bug in WSL or OpenCV and you could send it to authors of WSL and/or OpenCV

Comment: i have the same setup and just tested this and got the same result. most likely a bug with wslg's gui system